# What are the parameters in device.drag method in AndroidViewClient?

Tags: drag, androidviewclient

what does the orientation parameter in the drag method do? 
Also when I change the duration and/or steps, it does not make that much difference

vc.device.drag(start, end, duration, steps, orientation):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code (the greatest of Open Source):

```
def drag(self, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), duration, steps=1, orientation=-1):
    '''
    Sends drag event in PX (actually it's using C{input swipe} command).

    @param (x0, y0): starting point in PX
    @param (x1, y1): ending point in PX
    @param duration: duration of the event in ms
    @param steps: number of steps (currently ignored by @{input swipe})
    @param orientation: the orientation (-1: undefined)
    '''

    self.__checkTransport()
    if orientation == -1:
        orientation = self.display['orientation']
    (x0, y0) = self.__transformPointByOrientation((x0, y0), orientation, self.display['orientation'])
    (x1, y1) = self.__transformPointByOrientation((x1, y1), orientation, self.display['orientation'])

    version = self.getSdkVersion()
    if version <= 15:
        raise RuntimeError('drag: API <= 15 not supported (version=%d)' % version)
    elif version <= 17:
        self.shell('input swipe %d %d %d %d' % (x0, y0, x1, y1))
    else:
        self.shell('input touchscreen swipe %d %d %d %d %d' % (x0, y0, x1, y1, duration))
```

also, keep in mind that one of the main objectives of AndroidViewClient and [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) is to generate tests that can run under a wide range of conditions, not just the one present when they were generated. You can run the same test on a different device, screen or resolution. Also, you can run the same test under a different **orientation** and you don't want the test to be affected by that fact, then when the test is generated the **orientation** is saved and eventually the coordinates translated if when run the device was rotated.

**duration** usage depends on the android version, as you can see in the source.

**steps**, as stated, are currently ignored.